# "Double vision" in rviz

Tags: ros-melodic, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm testing out a RGBD camera and rviz, but I've noticed that I'm getting "double vision" in PointCloud2. This is me holding up one finger:

[image: image description]

As you can see, there's a clone of the shadow of my hand and finger. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331860/%22double-vision%22-in-rviz/) by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2019-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no double vision for your finger. The actual representation of your finger is the (single) red one, below. You get two fingers shown in the background, because of the way these cameras work. You can think of these as shadows of your real finger.

The device projects an IR pattern onto the scene and captures it, then. So one shadow comes from your finger blocking the projector (so no IR patter is behind your finger) the other one comes from your finger blocking the view of the camera (it can see no pattern behind your finger). Since camera and projector are mounted at an angle, you end up with two shadows.

Explanation of the camera:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uq9SEJxZiUg

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2019-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2